# How can you bind to when an element is attached to the dom (especially in Backbone.js)?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

In Backbone JS, the strategy is first rendering everything out in an detached element. Then when ready attaching it to the DOM.

I would like to bind to when that element is finally attached to the DOM (and then run some functions like say triggering some click events or whatnot.

Comment: Couldn't you run these functions you speak of directly after attaching the element to the DOM? (i.e. `view.render(); $("#some_element").append(view.$el); view.$(".button").click();`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create your own custom events that other Backbone objects can subscribe to.  Trigger these when you add a view to the DOM.

`this.trigger('addedToDOM', this);`

...

`viewtoBeAdded.bind('addedToDOM', this.onAddedToDom);`

...

`onAddedToDom: function(viewThatWasAdded) { .. }`